# Direct access of attribute shows different value than object console output

Tags: javascript, object, browser, console, d3.js

I am crunching my head already for quite a time regarding a strange behavior of my js script. When I output the value `d.parent.x` to the console and it shows a different value, than when I print the `d.parent` to the console and browse for the value through the console.

In the screenshot you see that the object itself has a value x of 525.5, whereas the output of d.parent.x gives me 148.

I m not sure whether this is a js behavior or a behavior of the used [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.v2.js).

I created a jsfiddle for it ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/xbxyM/12/), [result](http://jsfiddle.net/xbxyM/12/embedded/result/)). When opening the console in Chrome or Safari you can see the output as in the screenshot.

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with console.log - it's referenced based and will basically end up caching results in some instances when logging objects.

To get around it you can usually do `console.log(JSON.stringify(d.parent))` but this doesn't work in your case due to cyclic references. I just set a breakpoint in your script and looked at `d.parent` and `d.parent.x`.

[image]

They do indeed result in the same value  which is the value that `console.log(d.parent.x)` shows in your original code.

Comment: Wow, so much insight. Thanks for clarifying!